# fetch works but push doesn't in gitlab repo

Tags: git, push, gitlab

I have created a gitlab repo and cloned on my local machine. I made some changes by login to gitlab and fetched into my local and it works fine. But, I cannot push any changes made locally to gitlab project. I have added the public sshkey into my gitlab account for ssh access.

Push using https works fine as well.

This is the error when I try to push to gitlab project using ssh method.

> GitLab: You don't have permission fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and
>   the repository exists.

Please advise what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All seems fine.
But can you give use the result of the following command:

```
 git remote -v
```

Moreover if the ssh key your trying to use is not id_rsa you may have some other problems.

(I would have leave this as a comment but I have not the 50 points needed)

Comment: git remote -v
origin git@gitlab.com:user/project.git (fetch)
origin git@gitlab.com:user/project.git (push)

Comment: nothing abnormal here. Are you using the id_rsa ssh key ?

Comment: what is the command you use to push to the remote repository ? `git push origin master` ?

Comment: The problem may come from gitlab, you may not have the right permission in it.

Comment: probably something wrong. could  not figure it out. but deleted everything on gitlab and re-created. its all working fine . thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but may be relevant for someone looking for the some issue now.

I had some issues with Gitlab permissions. Even with Admin privileges in the Gitlab, SSH correctly configured and all working as supposed but could not push. Some things you may check:

- Branch is not protected in the Project Settings
- Added as member in the project explicitly
- Have not been banned after a lot of auth retried by security measures such as [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/). Can make you lose good hours if using hosted Gitlab in AWS until you figure it out.